# How to get ID of select when user selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select option. Now I want to get `id` of `select` when user selected option. Ex: If I selected Option1 then `alert` `id="my_select1"` and if I selected MyOption2 then `alert` `id="my_select2"`. How can I do that?

```
<select id="my_select1">
  <option value="o1" id="id1">Option1</option>
  <option value="o2" id="id2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select id="my_select2">
  <option value="mo1" id="mid1">MyOption1</option>
  <option value="mo2" id="mid2">MyOption2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('select').change(function() {

  alert($(this).attr('id'))//use attr() to get id
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_select1">
  <option value="o1" id="id1">Option1</option>
  <option value="o2" id="id2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select id="my_select2">
  <option value="mo1" id="mid1">MyOption1</option>
  <option value="mo2" id="mid2">MyOption2</option>
</select>
```

1. Use `.attr()` to get `id`
2. Use `$(this)` to get the id of the select that made the change

Answer (score 0):

Bind a change event handler and use `this.id` to get `id` of the event fired select tag. Although you can use [`$(this).attr('id')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the `id` attribute value.

```js
$('#my_select1,#my_select2').change(function() {
  alert(this.id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_select1">
  <option value="o1" id="id1">Option1</option>
  <option value="o2" id="id2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select id="my_select2">
  <option value="mo1" id="mid1">MyOption1</option>
  <option value="mo2" id="mid2">MyOption2</option>
</select>
```